# Window function, trying to order by created_at from a column in join table without grouping

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I am trying to select all thread subjects for a particular user but I want to order by the most recent thread via recent message that was sent. Here is my database schema.

```
create table thread (
    id bigserial primary key,
    subject text not null,
    created timestamp with time zone not null default current_timestamp
);

create table thread_account (
    account bigint not null references account(id) on delete cascade,
    thread bigint not null references thread(id) on delete cascade
);
create index thread_account_account on thread_account(account);
create index thread_account_thread on thread_account(thread);

create table message (
    id bigserial primary key,
    thread bigint not null references thread(id) on delete cascade,
    content text not null,
    account bigint not null references account(id) on delete cascade,
    created timestamp with time zone not null default current_timestamp
);
create index message_account on message(account);
create index message_thread on message(thread);
```

Then I was doing a query like

```
select * 
FROM thread_account 
JOIN thread on thread.id = thread_account.thread
JOIN message on message.thread = thread_account.thread 
WHERE thread_account.account = 299
ORDER BY message.created desc;
```

But this just gives back a list of all thread subjects for every entry where there is a message. (JOIN message on message.thread = thread_account.thread) seems to be the issue. I've been told I need a window function but can't seem to figure them out. This is for Postgres by the way.

Comment: I am not understanding your problem, pls explain more, or write what output you want

Comment: Sorry about that. So I have 5 threads and the threads only have id, created, and subject columns. But I want to return the threads in order of recent messages sent. IE message.created rather than thread.created. Messages are joined to threads via thread_account.

I would liek just the 5 threads returned in order of recent messages. But i am currently returning 1000 entries (one for every message in the entire database). 

Does that make sense?

Comment: working on your query.

Comment: Explain this : IE message.created rather than thread.created

Comment: I want the threads to be updated by the most recent messages sent. Messages are attached to threads via thread_account table

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like:

```
select * 
FROM thread_account 
JOIN thread on thread.id = thread_account.thread
JOIN message on message.thread = thread_account.thread 
WHERE thread_account.account = 299
ORDER BY MAX(message.Created) OVER (PARTITION BY thread.id) desc;
```

The small tweak is the window function in the ORDER BY. This will partition your result set by `thread.id`, so you will end up with chunks of records for each `thread.id`, then it finds the `max(message.created)` for each of those chunks of records. Then it uses that `max(message.created)` to sort the result set.

Window Functions are little tricky to wrap your head around at first, but just think of them as chunking up your records (Partitioning) and then applying some sort of aggregation or function to one of the fields in that chunk, such as `Max()`.

---

As mentioned in your comment, you don't want to see the information for the messages, rather just the threads. You just need to specify which fields you want in your result set in your `SELECT` portion of the query. You can use either `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT` to get a single record back for each thread.

Furthermore, we can show the Last Message Date in the results by copying that window function up into the `Select` portion as well:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    thread_account.*, 
    thread.*, 
    MAX(message.Created) OVER (PARTITION BY thread.id) as Last_Message_Date
FROM thread_account 
JOIN thread on thread.id = thread_account.thread
JOIN message on message.thread = thread_account.thread 
WHERE thread_account.account = 299
ORDER BY MAX(message.Created) OVER (PARTITION BY thread.id) desc;
```

If you only want certain fields from either `Thread` or `Thread_Account` then you just get more explicit in the `SELECT` portion of the query like `SELECT DISTINCT Thread.Id, Thread_Account.Account, etc..`

Comment: So this still returns all of the entries for all of the messages that I have in the database. IE 50 messages for thread 1, 300 for thread 2. I'm looking for just the thread's (not messages and entries for the messages, just orderingby the messages created at). We're getting closer! Thanks for your help

Comment: Gotcha. I've added some additional help to the answer to use `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` as well as how to be more explicit about which fields are returned from your joined tables.

Comment: Ohhh this is awesoe! Thanks so much. That fixed it. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @user3858739 This is wrong is at least two ways. Check the results carefully before you adopt it.

Comment: Hahha really? @ClodoaldoNeto why is it wrong. It seems to be working

Comment: I like his answer specifically for this question, but I wanted to use window functions since it was mentioned in the question. I see no problem with this query. Maybe I'm missing something, but I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

The very handy [`distinct on`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) makes it easy:

```
select distinct on (t.id) *
from
    thread_account ta
    inner join
    thread t on t.id = ta.thread
    inner join
    message m on m.thread = ta.thread 
where ta.account = 299
order by t.id, m.created desc
```

For just the thread info do instead:

```
select distinct on (t.id) t.*
```